# ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework can not add to xcode7 project

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, ios9, parsefacebookutils

I have recently updated my os to iOS 9 ,also use new xcode7

start my application to parse all done good but whenever I add 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework' framework to my project It give me error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFErrorUtilities", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookUtils.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I follow parse and facebook developer guideline to do this but simple framework can not add to my project

I also download new parse sdk 1.8.5 and remove old framework and add again, clean my project 
But can't get the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many attempts I have solved this issues
I have created cocoapods with my existing project and its work very smoothly...

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just ran into the same problem. Basically I deleted my tests target. I found this:

Errors When Compiling iOS 8, Xcode 6.0.1
http://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=F42D8239A330C321132944A&currentPage=3

Which basically says that:

Click on the name of your project on the list of files/folders on the left in Xcode (at the very top of the list). Look at the "Targets" section on the left-hand side of the window to the right. Likely, there's two listed with the second being a "test" item. Right-click on that item and select "delete". Then try to run the project again. See screenshot below for a visual cue.

And a picture to help you out:[image]

or try this

1.Make new file: ⌘cmd+N

2.iOS/Mac > Other > PCH File > YourProject-Prefix.PCH".

3.Project > Build Settings > Search: "Prefix Header"
.
4.Under "Apple LLVM 6.0" you will get the Prefix Header key

5.Type in: "YourProjectName/YourProject-Prefix.PCH"

6.Clean project: ⌘cmd+⇧shift+K

7.Build project: ⌘cmd+B

Comment: I also have google plus login with this same project

Comment: delete the unwanted and unused frameworks from the project

Comment: This happened to me when I renamed my project. To solve this, Select Targets/Build Settings and search for the old project name and replace with the new name .some times only work

Comment: how to check this old name , and also i didn't change my project name so its not neccessary